# How do you write this differently? $(A\not\subseteq B) \wedge (B \not\subseteq A) \wedge ((B \cap A) \neq \emptyset)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I like to write this different, maybe there is a better and shorter way of doing it..? So we have $(A\not\subseteq B) \wedge (B \not\subseteq A) \wedge ((B \cap A) \neq \emptyset)$

which should mean that: No element of $A$ is an element of $B$ and no element of $B$ is an element of $A$ and the intersection of $A,B$ is not empty.

Then this would mean the same as above, right? 
$$(A \neq B) \wedge ((A \cap B) \neq \emptyset)$$

Maybe a more elegant/shorter way of doing this differently?

Comment: > No element of A is an element of B and no element of B is an element of A and the intersection of A,B is not empty.


This is entirely incorrect. $A \not\subseteq B$ does not mean "no member of $A$ is a member of $B$. It means "not every member of $A$ is a member of $B$. 

Also, neither $(A \not\subseteq B)\wedge(B\not\subseteq A)$ nor "no element of $A$ is an element of $B$ and no element of $B$ is an element of $A$" is equivalent to $A \neq B$.

Comment: No, the symbol $A\not\subseteq B$ means that $A$ is not contained in $B$, so *some element of $A$ is not an element of $B$*.

Comment: Usually, having an example in mind helps. Try to think of the Venn diagram for the original statement. A more concrete example of the original statement is $A=\left\{1,2\right\}$, $B=\left\{2,3\right\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line translates to: There exists elements that are in $A$ but not in $B$ and there exists elements that are in $B$ but not in $A$ and there exists elements that are both in $A$ and $B$.

Both your expression by words and your second mathematical statement do **NOT** express that.

There are many ways to write your initial statement down, one could use the complement operator or the differences operator for sets.

Answer (score 1):

You've written three different things. The statement in the title says that $A, B$ are overlapping, but neither contains the other. The statement in English in your text is always false: if no element of $A$ is an element of $B$ then their intersection cannot be non-empty, because an element in the intersection is in both $A$ and $B$. The formula in your text states that $A, B$ are distinct but overlapping sets, but allows for the possibility that one is a subset of the other.

I do not think there is a meaningfully shorter way to write what you have written in your title. (Furthermore, just in case this was your reason: shorter is often not better, *simpler* is better, and the statement in your title is quite easy to read.)